# Hover doesn't work in bootstrap modal image

Tags: html, css, forms

Hope someone can help me with this.Here is my Html code:

[image]

**and here is my css code:**

[image]
And Here is my code from codepen:
`enter code here`[And Here is my code from codepen](https://codepen.io/citakilkay/pen/yLayMeK)
I tried with every parent elements with hover. it doesn't work until coming '#idhireme' line.
When I hover the image nothing changes. Is there anyone know why doesn't it work?

Comment: Please add your code as a text, not an image. And a snippet as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the hover doesn't reach the image.

Try to apply the `:hover` pseudo-class to the parent element:

```
card-radius:hover card-gray { 
  filter: grayscale(0%) !important;
}
```

If it doesn't work, try one level up.

Comment: I tried it now.It doesn't work on until coming to the 'modal fade' class which is beginning of the modal.

Answer (score 0):

I forgot the `<div class= "modal-content">` bootstrap class.I put it after `class="modal-dialog"`.